# Get instant current il milliampere from Android using adb

Tags: android

I need to calculate the power consumption of an Android smartphone using adb.
I know that there is Google Battery Historian, and I also know the command:

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats
```

But I need something different: I want to launch an app (youtube for example) using adb for 10 minutes and, using adb (wireless) I want to collect the power consumption in milliamperes every second.
I know that there is a way to get the mA, but I cannot understand how.